# How to disable the loading gif in first load of product list page

Tags: magento2, product-images, products, loading, gif

I'm having a problem.
In product list page, such as "Category" page.
I choose Color = Orange and it will reload the page.
For every next reload page, the product image will show the loading gif for a few mili-seconds before it show the real picture.
[image]
So how to disable this loading gif?
Thanks